# VBA - Check What User has Excel Workbook Open on Server

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to determine what user has an excel workbook open on a shared network server. I have written a basic routine with two separate functions that try to achieve this using the 'winmgmts' and 'ADsSecurityUtility' objects, functions are based off the following links:

[How to tell if an Excel 2007 spreadsheet is open and WHO has it open using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555522/how-to-tell-if-an-excel-2007-spreadsheet-is-open-and-who-has-it-open-using-vbscr)

[Get owner of file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631310/get-owner-of-file-on-disk)

My code is provided below:

```
Sub wkbk_open()

    wkbk_name = "Project List LIVE.xlsm"
    wkbk_lock_file_path = "X:\~$" & wkbk_name

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objFSO.FileExists(wkbk_lock_file_path) Then
        Debug.Print "The file is locked by " & GetFileOwner(wkbk_lock_file_path)
        Debug.Print "The file is locked by " & GetFileOwner2(wkbk_lock_file_path)
    Else
        Debug.Print "The file is available"
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(strFileName)
    'http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/security/ownership/scr_1386.asp
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
    objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strFileName & "'")
    intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)

    If intRetVal = 0 Then
       GetFileOwner = objSD.Owner.Name
    Else
       GetFileOwner = "Unknown"
    End If
End Function

Function GetFileOwner2(strFileName) As String

'On Error Resume Next
Dim secUtil As Object
Dim secDesc As Object
Set secUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(strFileName, 1, 1)
GetFileOwner2 = secDesc.Owner
End Function
```

However, when I execute this code. Function 1 returns:

```
The file is locked by
```

and function two returns:

```
The file is locked by S-1-5-21-3895087902-3842375508-912246676-1159
```

Does anyone know how to either get the winmgts service to return an owner OR convert the SID (Security Identifier) to a username?

Comment: FWIW - both functions work for me.  (i.e. `GetFileOwner` returns my network userid, and `GetFileOwner2` returns my domain and userid.)

Comment: You keep looking for the owner of the file but you don't actually want to know that (the owner is the person that first created the file unless an admin then it's the administrator's group). You want who has the file open and you use this function `NetFileGetInfo` or `NetFileEnum` direct. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525378(v=vs.85).aspx Another way is IADsResource https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa706124(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @YowE3K did you run these functions on a file stored on your server? or locally on your computer. These functions work for me if the file is stored locally, but not if it is stored on the server.

Comment: @Noodles I am actually interrogating the excel lock file (system file prefixed with a ~$ that is auto created upon opening an excel workbook). Since this system file is created by the user that opened the workbook the owner should correctly return the user on the network that is currently accessing the file. Do you have an example of a VBA function that uses one of these methods you have suggested to successfully return the current user of a file?

Comment: This is best example, but it uses API call CopyMemory which I disagree with as a technique (it's not necessary but it works - don't think it's ok as a general thing). Here it is http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/network/netfileenum.htm

Comment: Maybe this applies. If file are created with DeleteOnClose flag they aren't written to disk usually - maybe that affects your code. I've done no experiments.

Comment: @Noodles Great thanks for the link. I'll have to do some experimentation with this and see if it works.

Comment: The file I tried accessing was on our company file server.  Are the files you are testing on ones that you have opened yourself as a test case?  If "real" files, is the owner showing correctly when you just look at the file owner using Windows Explorer?  (I know a userid that is no longer in existence will often show as just the SID, because it can no longer find the userid in whatever table the system uses for that purpose.)

Comment: @YowE3K Yes the files I am testing are ones I have opened myself for testing. I also did test a file another user had open and the same error is returned. Looking at "Real" and lock files in windows explorer the owner is shown correctly, i.e. "Domain Name" & "User Name"